# How can I pass query string on Firefox command-line?

Tags: firefox, debian

I try `firefox-esr /path/to/file?field=value` but seem Firefox encode the query string to the plain URL with complain `File not found`

```
$ firefox-esr --version
Mozilla Firefox 60.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`/path/to/file?field=value` and `file:///path/to/file?field=value` is not equal.
Just add the `file://` protocol prefix to make Firefox correct handle your [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)